# MKV File causing VLC to stop playing abruptly

Tags: 22.04, graphics, video, intel-graphics, integrated

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a 10-year-old, x86_64 Dell Latitude laptop with an Intel processor, and integrated graphics. Apart from being choppy on Windows, there was this issue when it came to playing video files (MKV, and others) where VLC would abruptly stop playing a file that would otherwise play just fine on other machines. Except for the choppy video playback, this issue has persisted on Ubuntu, which causes me to think that there's something wrong with the video drivers or the GPU itself. Till now, I've tried to install the Haruna Media Player, which for some reason stops responding at the same point of a particular video as VLC stops, but continues playing after dismissing the resulting dialog message. Note that this issue isn't specific to the file I mentioned in this post. Any idea what the underlying culprit could be, and how I can fix this?